# Merge/synonymize bootstrap and bootstrapping

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, retag-request

On Stack Overflow, we have:

[bootstrap](/questions/tagged/bootstrap) - 248 questions

[bootstrapping](/questions/tagged/bootstrapping) - 151 questions

[bootstrapper](/questions/tagged/bootstrapper) - 125 questions

Shouldn't these 3 be merged into [bootstrap](/questions/tagged/bootstrap)?

Comment: No, [bootstrap] can mean a number of things.

Comment: And `[bootstrapper]` means something very different from `[bootstrap]` and `[bootstrapping]`, from an installer's point of view.

Comment: It is also used for `twitter-bootstrap` sometimes, those questions should be retagged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[bootstrap](/questions/tagged/bootstrap), and [bootstrapping](/questions/tagged/bootstrapping) could be eventually merged, but I don't have any reason to believe they should. *Bootstrap* is normally used to mean "a self-sustaining process that proceeds without external help," while *bootstrapping* is normally used to mean the phase during which an Operating System (or a web application) initialize itself.

[bootstrapper](/questions/tagged/bootstrapper) is really referring to something specific about the Composite Application Library. The [bootstrapper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921139%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx) is, "responsible for the initialization of an application built using the Composite Application Library."
If it is really too ambiguous, [bootstrapper](/questions/tagged/bootstrapper) can be changed to use a prefix for the technology using it, such as in [prism-bootstrapper](/questions/tagged/prism-bootstrapper).

I found just 3 questions using [bootstrapper](/questions/tagged/bootstrapper) without referring to .NET applications. I removed the tag from those questions; in this way, [bootstrapper](/questions/tagged/bootstrapper) can be renamed, if it is really necessary.

Comment: [bootstrap] is too ambiguous to be merged with [bootstrapping].

Comment: That is the reason I said _could_, and not _can_. What I mean is they could eventually be merged, but I don't have any reason to believe they should be merged. My answer is more focused on [tag:bootstrapper].